# Bulk Update to Null on numeric column in postgres

Tags: python, postgresql

I am trying to do bulk update to postgres DB from python. The update query is setting to NULL for a column which is of numeric type. Here is the code snippet for the same.

```
 update_query = "UPDATE items SET qoh = data.qoh FROM (VALUES %s) " \
                       "AS data ( company_id, item_id, qoh )  " \
                       "WHERE items.company_id = data.company_id " \
                       "AND items.item_id = data.item_id"
        data = [(2, 1, 10)]
        psycopg2.extras.execute_values(self.cursor, update_query, data)
        data = [(2, 1, None)]
        psycopg2.extras.execute_values(self.cursor, update_query, data)
```

The Error i am getting is

```
Failed to do pull of data  Error: ---  column "qoh" is of type numeric but expression is of type text
LINE 1: UPDATE items SET qoh = data.qoh FROM (VALUES (2,1,NULL)) AS ...
                               ^
```

Comment: Please change `qoh = data.qoh` to `qoh = data.qoh::numeric` and test again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestion by Pooya worked for me

Please change qoh = data.qoh to qoh = data.qoh::numeric and test again